# ArcPy can I delete the 9th column if I don't know its field name?

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes

Is there a way to delete a field based on its number, rather than field name? For example, if the field name is `FID_myshp` I would do `arcpy.DeleteField_management(newshp, ['FID_myshp'])` but the name of the field to delete changes, and I would just rather delete the 9th column because I am sure it will always be the 9th column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one approach that gathers a list of field names with a list comprehension and selects the 9th field name in the list for deletion.

```
import arcpy

shp = r'C:\path\to\your\shapefile.shp'

# Get a list of all the field names
fields = [x.name for x in arcpy.ListFields(shp)]

# Delete the 9th field in the list
arcpy.DeleteField_management(shp, fields[8])
```